# Splunk extract fields from source

Tags: splunk

I have log entries all having a source file like:

> /openshift/{openshift_container_id}/{openshift_container_name}/{openshift_image_name}/{openshift_pod_name}/{openshift_namespace}.{docker_stream}

Is it possible to have parts of the log source as fields?
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rex field=source "/openshift/(?<openshift_container_id>[^/]+)/(?<openshift_container_name>[^/]+)/(?<openshift_image_name>[^/]+)/(?<openshift_pod_name>[^/]+)/(?<openshift_namespace>[^\.]+)\.(?<docker_stream>.*)"
```

You can use the `rex` command to extract fields from other fields using regular expressions